# CSS border specification matter in content height

Tags: html, css, border

I was working on this CSS, I have wrapped an article inside a div. I have given percentage width for both, and padding for the div. My padding seem "not applied" until I add border to the article. You can see the difference by commenting the border applied to the article. My article height shrink. Why is this happening?

```
<style>
body{
    margin:100px;
}
.content{
width:100%;   
padding:.9746589%;
background:green;
   }
  .content>article{
width:100%;
background:yellow;  
border:1px solid red;
 }

</style>
        <div class="content" role="main">
            <article>

                <p>This is my text!</p>
            </article>
        </div>
```

Comment: your padding seem apply very well.

Comment: Check this Fiddle its working.. http://jsfiddle.net/naE4W/1/ actually p tag adding margin top and bottom set margin zero to p tag

Comment: seems to work for me. what browsers are you testing with?

Comment: Ghodke your reply combined with BoltClock answers my question. But does the p that always have that margin by default or just for this case?

Answer (score 2):

There are default margins in your `p` element that are [collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) with your `article` element. When you add a border to your `article`, it prevents that collapse from happening and causes it to contain the `p` element and its default margins.

Your .9746589% padding is applied in both situations, but since you put it on `.content` it isn't actually affected by the margin collapse between its `article` and the `p` that's inside it. If you were to remove *that* as well as the border, though, then the margins would collapse across all elements and the green background would completely disappear. In other words, just like how your border is blocking margin collapse between `article` and `p`, your padding is also blocking margin collapse between `.content` and `article` and its contents.

Lastly, margins only collapse vertically, so setting width will never make a difference.

Comment: Your explanation and your reference is very helpful, and my other question, in this parent child relationship my understanding is what matter is the content,padding or border of the parent in order to avoid the collapse. Is this right?

Comment: @user1986244: Either padding or border. The reference link contains all the details.